# How can I set default database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, environment, multiple-databases

I have an application that use two databases. Now I have in development environment. How can I set the databases for each environment by default in Rails?
My database.yml looks like:

```
database1_dev:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: db1
  user: root
  password: asdf
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

database2_dev:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: db2
  user: root
  password: asdf
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: What do you mean by "application that uses two databases"? Does it need to connect to both the databases at the same time to function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a separate environment.  By default in a new project rails sets up test, production and development.  You need to setup development_2 or staging or whatever adequately describes what you're doing.

In your rails project in `config/environments` copy the development file to a new file with the name you're using for your environment.

Then in your `database.yml` file, make sure there is an entry named to match each environment. So if you have development and development_2 then your entries should be:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: db1 
  user: root
  password: asdf
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development_2:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: db2 
  user: root
  password: asdf
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

By default when you run a rails application it will be in development, so that is already selecting the `development` database from your yml file.

Now when you want to run in an alternative environment you'll just tell rails the env is `development_2`, if you're using the `rails server` command it will instead be

```
rails server -e development_2
```

Note that this new environment might break certain gems which are hard carded to work for only `staging`, `test`, `production` and `development`.